# Replace Scandit word from laser picker in sdk

Tags: angularjs, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

i have integrated the scandit sdk within my app. I want to replace the word scandit with some other name in my app. The scandit word is showing next to the laser while we scan. I want to replace that..